# Vector of Vector in a Java webservice

Tags: java, web-services, vector

I am writing a webservice method to return the values of a table.I am using two Vectors one for the column and another for the values of the table.The Vector used for Values of the table contain each row as a Vector.These methods are written inside an EJB and the webservice is deployed in Weblogic 10.3. I am able to hit the webservice and call the methods and able to fetch the columnnames Vector.However when I fetch the values Vector I am just getting the Object class reference(address).I think I have to add something in xmltype-mapping.xml and I have never worked on it.Can anyone suggest what should be done so that I can retrieve the values of the table too.

Comment: Haven't you simply lost the generics? Can't you cast the "inner" objects to `Vector`?

Comment: Btw `Vector` is obsolete, use `ArrayList` instead.

Comment: I am using Vector<Vector> only and the values are stored perfectly in the server side but when I retrieve in the client side I am getting the address of the Object in place of the individual Vectors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I am using Vector only and the values are stored perfectly in the server side but when I retrieve in the client side I am getting the address of the Object in place of the individual Vectors.

That's probably because you are trying to convert the `Vector<Vector>` to a String and passing the String.  You might be doing it explicitly by calling `vec.toString()`, or you might be doing something like this:

```
String element = "<something>" + vec + "</something>";
```

The problem is that the `Vector` class does not override the `toString()` method, and your code ends up calling `Object.toString()` ... which gives you the array's internal class name concatenated with the array's identity hashcode value.

That's what is happening, but I don't know what you need to do to fix it, given the technologies you are using.